# "Resource Injection" fixation in asp.net version 2.0

Tags: asp.net, code-injection

I have got a vulnerabilty while scanning with a tool  that is **"Resource Injection"**.

I am not able to find the solution for this issue.
The following code i am using

Me.FileUploadImg1.SaveAs(Me.Server.MapPath("~") & "\" & System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("library_video") & "\" & "E" & EventID & "\" & "A" &
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(txtAlbumID.Value) & "\" & HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(filenameonly))

The tool suggests the following solution:

**Fix Suggestions:**
The simplest way to fix XSS is to validate all information that comes from an outside source (i.e. user, infrastructure, external entities or
database systems). The validation of the data insures that the data contains no scripts. There are two main ways to validate the data: Filtering
all input and Escaping all output.

**Filtering All Input**
The safest and perhaps most effective method of addressing this vulnerability is to only accept data that is deemed valid and reject
everything else, known as a "positive" or "whitelist" filtering. For example, if the input data is expected to be numeric, then ensure that this is
the case by rejecting any input that is not. In addition to rejecting all data, a cleaning routine can be used, which checks for the existence of
special characters and replaces each with another character, such as a blank space.
A weak alternative to positive filtering is a "negative" or "blacklist" filtering. This is a dangerous strategy, because the set of possible bad data
is potentially infinite. Adopting this strategy means that one will have to maintain the list of "known bad" characters and patterns forever, and
one will by definition have incomplete protection.
Sanitization actions related to filtering and escaping generally involve discarding, rejecting, replacing, substituting, translating and encoding
the tainted input or output.
**Escaping All Output**
There are some scenarios we cannot rely on filtering to discard or reject data because the user is requested to provide input content that
includes special characters. To handle special input content with undiagnosed characters or scripts, it is often recommended to use escaping
mechanisms that allow transformation of the stream of encoded characters to a special sequence of character sets that cannot be executed
unexpectedly by the server or client.

Please sujestion some solution in c# code for this issue.

Comment: Hi @Ann L.,
For testing security we are using armorize - codesecure tool. But i am prety much sure that The fixation for this "Resource Injection" is not at all related to fixation of "cross site scripting".

Comment: **In the document the "Resource Injecton" is explained as:
Sample Code
One of the feature that's being widely used in ASP.NET is file download.**
*<%
strFileName = Request.QueryString["path"];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, fs.Length);
fs.Close();
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.End();
%>*

Comment: **Sample Attack on above code:**
A common approach is use "../" to change the directory. For example, "../../../../boot.ini" may allow the attackers to download C:\boot.ini from
the web server.

Comment: **Sample Fix Given in document:**
The most common approach is using a black list that filters strings like "../". However attackers may be able to use incanonical form to by
pass the black list.Using a white list provides great security. However the white list has to be crafted carefully and there may still be many
false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what tool you're using or how it works, I don't know precisely what it's looking for, but from the error message it seems concerned that you aren't validating input for possible script content, but instead are using it straight.

It could be the AppSettings that it's concerned with, but it's more likely to be txtAlbumID.Value.

You might want to check out this article : http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/prevent-cross-site-scripting-in-aspnet-w/240148552